# typeindependent object of template class

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

I am stuck again...

I have this template class:

```
template <typename a,typename b,typename c>
class myclass
{...};
```

I would like to declare an object of this class:

```
myclass<a,b,c> x;
```

This obviously does not work and I don't seem to be able to work out how to declare this object or if it even is possible.

I can make an object like this:

```
myclass<int,double,int> x;
```

But I don't want to specify the types of a,b,c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare it in template function or class, if I understand you correctly.

```
template <typename a,typename b,typename c>
void F(){
   myclass<a,b,c> x;
   ...
}
```

Otherwise it is forbidden by C++ and logic.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to make complicated template instances without spelling out the arguments is to have a type-deducing *function* template:

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
myclass<A, B, C> make_myclass(A a, B b, C C)
{
    return myclass<A, B, C>();   // or whatever
}
```

Usage:

```
auto x = make_myclass(1, 'x', -2.5f);   // x is a myclass<int, char, float>
```

Typical examples from the standard library that use this idiom are `make_shared`, `make_unique`, `make_pair`, `make_tuple`, `make_exception_ptr` and `make_optional`.

Answer (score 0):

there is no typeindependent object in c++, every object needs to be typed when they are declared. The only way to achieve type-erasure is by using technique like `void*` and pointer conversion, which you can find from [boost type erasure](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure.html)